# Spring + Thymeleaf can't pass the parameter correctly

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I can't pass the parameter correctly. I know the error was in the HTML.
The error was in the code `${vo.news.likeCount}`, `${vo.news.link}`, and so on.

But I don't know how to use it in the correct way. Thank you.

This is a thymeleaf template:

```
<div class="posts">
  <div th:each="vo : ${vos}">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="votebar">
        <button class="click-like up" aria-pressed="false" title="赞同"><i class="vote-arrow"></i>
          <span class="count"><span th:text="${vo.news.likeCount}"></span></span>
        </button>
        <button class="click-dislike down" aria-pressed="true" title="反对"><i class="vote-arrow"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" data-url="${vo.news.link}">
        <div>
          <img class="content-img" src="${vo.news.image}" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is class `ViewObject`:

```
public class ViewObject {

    private Map<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public void set(String key, Object value) {
        obj.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return obj.get(key);
    }
}
```

This is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"/", "/index"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String index(Model model) {
    List<News> newsList = newsService.getLatesNews(0, 0, 10);
    List<ViewObject> vos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (News news : newsList) {
        ViewObject vo = new ViewObject();
        vo.set("news", news);
        vo.set("user", userService.getUser(news.getUserId()));
        vos.add(vo);
    }

    model.addAttribute("vos", vos);
    return "home.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `vo.news.likeCount` means `vo.getNews().getLikeCount()`.  `ViewObject` doesn't have method `getNews()`.  You need to structure your expressions to look the same way they would in java.

```
<span th:text="${vo.get('news').likeCount}"></span>

<img class="content-img" src="${vo.get('news').image}" alt="">

<div class="content" data-url="${vo.get('news').link}">
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works!If you are free this time ,can you give a look at my another question posted recently.About null,please help me.they are the same program.